# Passing free-form commands to Ansible using complex-args form

Tags: ansible

I'm using programatically generated Ansible playbooks. In general, because playbooks are just YAML, this is straightforward.  However, when using the "simple" `key=value` form, playbooks *aren't* pure YAML -- they include content embedded a `shlex`-parsable form.

To avoid the ambiguity in this form (is that `key=value` pair an argument to the command or an argument for ansible?), and have only a single format to parse and generate, I'm unconditionally using the complex args mechanism demonstrated by example in [the ansible-examples repository](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/complex_args.yml).

This uses a syntax of the following kind:

```
action: module-name
args:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

...which is well and good. However, when trying to use this form for the `shell` or `command` modules ([whose documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) describes the actual command as being passed in an argument named `free_form`), this doesn't work so well:

```
action: shell
args:
  free_form: echo hello_world >/tmp/something
  creates: /tmp/something
```

When invoked, this runs the following:

```
/bin/sh -c " free_form='echo hello_world >/tmp/something'  "
```

...which is very much not what I'm trying to accomplish.

What's the right way to use Ansible modules taking "free-form" commands using pure YAML syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Don't use the `command`, `raw`, `script`, or `shell` modules. Write your own module that accepts the command as a "normal" argument.

**Long answer:**

In most cases, you can do this:

```
- shell: echo hello_world > /tmp/something
  args:
    creates: /tmp/something
```

However, this fails in some edge cases:

```
- shell: echo hello_world > creates=something
  args:
    creates: creates=something  # The file is named "creates=something"
```

I don't know of a general way to handle this, but a bash-specific solution is:

```
- shell: echo hello_world > "creates=something"
  args:
    creates: creates=something
```

Comment: Is there a data structure I can pass to any compliant YAML generator to make it emit `- shell: ...`? If this structure is something that can only be reliably generated by hand, that somewhat defeats the point of the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I don't think you can escape the `...` part in general. If you look at [`library/commands/command`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v1.6.3/library/commands/command#L188), you'll find a pretty generous regex matching `creates=`, `removes=`, `chdir=`, and so on. If you need to guarantee *any* command can be passed through, you'll have to write your own module.

Comment: Fair 'nuff. This is, in my mind, a significant design misfeature... but, well, is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) now.

```
# You can also use the 'args' form to provide the options. This command
# will change the working directory to somedir/ and will only run when
# /path/to/database doesn't exist.
- command: /usr/bin/make_database.sh arg1 arg2
  args:
    chdir: somedir/
    creates: /path/to/database
```

Note that there is no parameter named 'free_form'.

Comment: Does presence of `args` prevents `k=v` pairs from being parsed out from `command`, should any exist? (If so, this addresses the ambiguity cleanly; otherwise, it would seem to still exist).